# how to fix 'Property does not exist on type 'JQueryHTMLElement'. any".' error in angular project?

Tags: jquery, angular

I am working on an Angular2 project.

I'm trying to create a list of elements that change the order randomly.

I'm trying this jQuery code, but I get this error:

```
"Property 'sort' does not exist on type 'JQueryHTMLElement'.any".
```

This is the jquery code:

```
$(".allContent").append($(".allContent .content").sort(function () {
    return Math.random() - 0.5;
}));
```

The html code:

```
<div class="allContent">
    <div class="content">a</div>
    <div id="headline">b</div>
    <div class="content">c</div>
    <div class="content">d</div>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Any reason why jQuery? You'd want to avoid using jQuery for DOM manipulation otherwise you'd run into many issues. You can do this without jQuery.

Comment: do you have an idea?